# Loop through var file on Ansible playbook then run all the roles in playbook in sequence

Tags: ansible

I am trying to find a way where I can run the playbook in loop in sequence. i.e. all the roles run with one value before going through again with the second one and so on.

I have tried this but each role is going through the loop before the second one runs. I want both roles to run before it loops through the second item.

**for instance: my structure**

```
group_vars:
  - sys_stuff.yml
roles:
  - role 1
  - role 2
  - role 3
playbook.yml
```

sys_stuff.yml has

```
onesie:
    memory: 1024
    cpu: 4
    email: blabla@bla
twosie:
    memory: 512
    cpu: 2
    email: aa@bla.bla
```

my playbook.yml:

```
- name: looping though tests
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_role:
        name: display_msg
      with_items: "{{ sys_stuff }}"      
      loop_control:
        loop_var: sys_name
    - include_role:    
        name: test_role
      with_items: "{{ sys_stuff }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: sys_name
```

one of the roles:

```
- name: msg in role 1
  debug:
    msg: "HELLO {{ sys_name }}"
```

current output:

```
TASK [include_role : test_role] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [test_role : msg in role1.yml] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "HELLO onesie"
}

TASK [test_role : msg in role1.yml] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "HELLO twosie"
}
TASK [display_msg : msg in display_role] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I am a messege on display message role onesie"
}

TASK [display_msg : fail] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost]

TASK [display_msg : msg in display_role] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "I am a messege on display message role twosie"
}
```

**What i would like is**

```
   run 1st role and output HELLO onsie
   run 2nd role and output I am a messege on display message role onsie

   run 1st role and outpul HELLO twosie
   run 2nd role and output I am a messege on display message role twosie
```

This way if 1st fails, it can still go through other items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution (implementation not tested you may have to adjust a bit) is to move the loop out of your role include on a higher level task include.

For example:

Create a `my_role_sequence.yml` file with:

```
---
- include_role:
    name: display_msg
- include_role:    
    name: test_role
```

Modify your playbook to loop through this include:

```
- name: looping though tests
  hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: my_role_sequence.yml
      loop: "{{ lookup('dict', sys_stuff) }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: sys_name
```

Meanwhile you probably have better option using directly your inventory (looping on a group at play level, eventually delegating to localhost) and taking advantage of the `serial` config option at play level as explained in [the rolling upgrade](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/guide_rolling_upgrade.html#the-rolling-upgrade) scenario.

Comment: Thanks, this is one way of doing it. It has worked with the example. I will try with the whole thing.
Little adjustment for the above example. It needs `"{{ lookup('dict', sys_stuff) }}"` in the loop

Comment: Updated according to your return.